# ASP.NET MVC and Providing Third-Party API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

I'm developing a web app. This is more of a line-of-business app rather than a web site. I'm using ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server 2008, and I've purchased LLBLGen. I need to provide an some sort of API to third parties. For instance, if this was a medical app, third parties might need to CRUD patients, retrieve complex reports, engage certain kinds of workflows, etc.

What is the best way to do this with MVC without going to the architecture astronaut route. Do I need a whole "web service" type layer or can I re-use my controllers in MVC? Does it make sense to have this kind of API exposed through MVC? Optimally, I need a solution that involves the least amount of code repitition. I've found some stuff on doing REST with MVC but some of it is rather ambiguous and I'm not sure if it makes sense. I need a reasonable API but I'm not required to follow all the tenets of the REST religion or anything like that. I just need some sort of API in addition to providing the HTML front-end to the site, be it REST, SOAP, whatever.

Also, what are some options for dealing with URLs? Not everything in the app maps to something like site/products/product-id. Some of it involves engaging complex workflows, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to have a web site and a web service then I would consider separating the data access and entities layers out from the MVC.

That way, your web service can do the same things that your website can. I would have a service layer that they both interact with. After which point the calls then go to the database and return the objects, and neither the web service nor the website should be able to interact with this layer.

This concept is also known as [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

You can't/shouldn't reuse your MVC controllers in your web service. If they're so alike that they're indistinguishable, then consider writing your website to be a client of the web service, rather than being part of the same solution.